# extend sealed class with properties

Tags: c#

I want to extend the `Rectangle` class. Currently this class has the properties `left`, `right`, ... and I want to add the properties `topLeft`, `topRight`, ...

I know I could create some extension methods like

```
public static Point TopLeft(this Rectangle rect)
{
    return new Point(rect.Left, rect.Top);
}
```

but I would like to add this as a property. I thought about inheriting from `Rectangle` and adding the missing information

```
internal class Rect : Rectangle
{
    public Point TopLeft
    {
        get
        {
            return new Point(X, Y);
        }
    }

    public Point TopRight
    {
        get
        {
            return new Point(X + Width, Y);
        }
    }
}
```

but `Rectangle` is a sealed class.

> cannot derive from sealed type 'Rectangle'

So it is not possible to extend this class?

Comment: `rect.Location` for `rect.TopLeft` and `rect.Location + rect.Size` for `rect.BottomRight`

Comment: `sealed` is meant to [prevent other classes from inheriting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed). So the answer is currently no, not possible, at least until we have [extension everything](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11159), hopefully in C# 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [adapter pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/adapter-design-pattern):

```
internal class RectAdapter
{  
    private Rect _rect;

    public RectAdapter(Rectangle rect)
    {
        _rect = rect;
    }

    public Point TopLeft
    {
        get
        {
            return new Point(_rect.X, _rect.Y);
        }
    }

    public Point TopRight
    {
        get
        {
            return new Point(_rect.X + _rect.Width, _rect.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

You can't inherit from the `Rectangle` but you can take it as a constructor parameter. And if you don't want to override other behaviour just delegate them to `Rectangle` by using `_rect`, for example:

```
public void Intersect(Rectangle rect) => _rect.Intersect(rect);
```